# Value of optional type '()?' not unwrapped

Tags: swift, unwrap

As far as I can tell, the optional failure block in the code below is already unwrapped with the `?` but xCode has been complaining about my syntax. If you look closely at the `success` block, it looks exactly like the `failure` block but somehow, xCode isn't flagging the `success` block.  I've encountered this problem before and managed to get rid of the problem with a build clean, but not this time. Has anyone encountered similar problems?

```
public func authorizeLogin(token: String, success: (() -> ())?, failure: (() -> ())?) {
        let path = "me/two-step/push-authentication"
        let requestUrl = self.pathForEndpoint(path, withVersion: ServiceRemoteRESTApiVersion_1_1)

        let parameters  = [
            "action"        : "authorize_login",
            "push_token"    : token
        ]

        api.POST(requestUrl,
            parameters: parameters,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
                success?()
            },
            failure:{ (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                failure?()
            })
    }
```

Here's the screenshot with the error message:

```
value of optional type '()?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a compiler issue (maybe cache). The reported type is not correct, it should have beed `(()->())?`, not just `()?`. The compiler seems to think that `failure` is a `Void`

Comment: Is there a way to clean up cache?

Comment: You can delete xcode's cache folder, it's located somewhere like ~/Library/Caches/Xcode/..., you should be able to find it on SO.

Comment: I just tried `clean`, `clean build folder`, and removed all `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/` but the problem continues to linger.

Comment: Try also deleting `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Comment: Just tried that too. :(

Answer (score 1):

Something looks really fishy in your code...both your `failure` closure and your `success` closure seem to be trying to call themselves. For example:

```
success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, response: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            success?() // <- This appears to be trying to call
                       //    the parameter itself
        }
```

That will never work. It's like writing,

```
let add: () -> () = { add() }
```

which gives the error `error: variable used within its own initial value`

I think that the error message you are getting is misleading, and what you need to do is write closures for the `success` and `failure` parameters that don't call themselves.